# Comparison between uint8_t and String

Tags: microcontroller, c, arm, stm32

I have a very fundamental question regarding string comparison..

I implemented a USART to PC with STM32L0 Nucleo board, and I can type something in terminal and receive it on the micro as follows:

```
#define RXBUFFERSIZE 1
uint8_t aRxBuffer[RXBUFFERSIZE];

/** Put UART peripheral in reception process */
  if(HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, RXBUFFERSIZE, 0xFFFF) != HAL_OK)
    Error_Handler();
```

I want to compare the received data with a string, but the comparison doesn't work.

```
char *is_correct= "Y";
if (strcmp((char*) aRxBuffer, is_correct) == 0)
    DoSomething();
else
    DoSomethingElse();
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

How I set up the USART:

```
/* USART2 init function */
void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONEBIT_SAMPLING_DISABLED;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  HAL_UART_Init(&huart2);

}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(huart->Instance==USART2)
  {
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**USART2 GPIO Configuration    
    PA2     ------> USART2_TX
    PA3     ------> USART2_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  }

}
```

Comment: You haven't shown all the relevant code but one thing is because `aRxBuffer` is one byte long it can't be a null-terminated string?

Comment: @PeterJ that is probably the problem, the RxBuffer is somewhere in memory and depending on stuff behind it it will be a random length string.

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks. How do I convert aRxBuffer to a string?

Comment: `message` is still out of scope for us answerers, the problem could also be related to that.

Comment: If the data received isn't intended to be null-terminated, then you should use `memcmp` instead of `strcmp`, which only requires size of memory areas to compare. Note that the size should be the size of data you get, not of the whole buffer (if they aren't equal).

Comment: Oh no terrible mistake, 'message' should be is_correct. But in any case @PeterJ 's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the `strcmp` function and all other string functions the string must be null-terminated. For your example one way to do that would be something like the following to allocate one extra byte in the array and put a null-terminator at the end:

```
#define RXBUFFERSIZE 1
uint8_t aRxBuffer[RXBUFFERSIZE + 1];
if(HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, RXBUFFERSIZE, 0xFFFF) != HAL_OK)
    ....
aRxBuffer[RXBUFFERSIZE] = 0;
```

Although for a single character compare like you have at the moment there's no need for a string comparison, you could use a character compare on the first and only element of the array:

```
if (aRxBuffer[0] == 'Y')
    DoSomething();
else
    DoSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 1):

The strcmp needs a null terminator, but there's another function you could use to compare strings which is [strncmp](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strncmp.php) which takes in the number of characters you want to compare. So you could end up doing:

```
char *is_correct= "Y";
if (strncmp((char*) aRxBuffer, message,strlen(message) ) == 0)
    DoSomething();
else
    DoSomethingElse();
```

This is also assuming that the `message` variable is a fixed string.

Comment: Be careful, though: `strncmp` is not a drop-in replacement for `strcmp`. For example, `strncmp("YB", "YA", 1)` will say that the strings match. That might be okay, but it might also be a trap.

Answer (score -1):

Why bother with strcmp or strncmp while you can simply do this:

```
uint8_t aRxBuffer;
#define RXBUFFERSIZE (sizeof(aRxBuffer))

if(HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, (uint8_t *)&aRxBuffer, RXBUFFERSIZE, 0xFFFF) != HAL_OK)
    Error_Handler();

if(aRxBuffer == message)
   DoSomething();
else
   DoSomethingElse();
```

Comment: What's the point in casting pointer to `uint8_t` to pointer to `uint8_t`?

Comment: Maybe because the other approach is easier scalable to a password or something?

Comment: @Ruslan `&aRxBuffer` is not a pointer but a `const` pointer and depending on the signature of `HAL_UART_Receive`, you are not allowed to input a `const` pointer, so you have to cast it away. (The method should use a `const` pointer though)

Comment: @Arsenal well, the first line declares `aRxBuffer` to be `uint8_t`, not `const uint8_t`, so the pointer isn't a pointer to const nor pointer const. Though I now see that this is just a copy from the OP, not Alex's mistake.

Comment: @Ruslan never mind my comment, don't know what I was looking at, probably induced by current on going lints for `const` correctness...

Comment: Apart from the peculiar cast, I don't understand why this is getting down votes. If you only expect one single character, there's no need to bloat your code with numerous string handling functions. Common sense is a very useful tool when programming.

Comment: It's really bad coding style... I deserve that...